# SQL: having trouble writing a query

Tags: sql

I have a quite a complicated query (well I think anyway!) to write. It will include a lot of joins.

Here's the idea: a task is linked to a project, a project is linked to a context. A user can create a task and they will own that task. However, a user can create a team and share a project with that team. Therefore anyone who is part of that team can see that project and it's tasks.

I want to query a list of tasks that 1) belong to the current user for their current context. and 2) the user can see as a result of being linked to a project via a team.

I want to show the tasks title and the projects name it belongs to.

When joining a team a user specifies which context will contain projects of that team. The idea being that contexts split projects up.

Here are the tables involved. Users_teams and projects_teams are used as link tables to join users to teams and projects to teams.

```
users
-----------------
id

tasks
------------------
id  |  user_id  |  project_id  |  title

projects
------------------
id  |  name  |  user_id  |  context_id

teams
------------------
id  |  name  |  user_id

users_teams
------------------
id  |  user_id  |  team_id  |  context_id

projects_teams
------------------
id  |  project_id  |  team_id
```

My first idea was to create 2 seperate queries; one to get a list of tasks the user owns and another to get a list of tasks that the user is linked to. The problem is that this way I can't really do ordering properly and my queries were giving strange results anyway. I thought maybe there was a way to do it all in one query?

My first query would simply be:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
JOIN projects on tasks.project_id = projects.id
WHERE tasks.user_id = 2 AND projects.context_id = 5
```

I guess the second would involve joining the users_teams, projects_teams tables.

Comment: I have not yet figured out what you want to show! :S

Comment: 1) can you upload an sql file with the structure and some test data? 2) do you have any requirements? I see it done using subqueries (but that might not be wanted)

Comment: @ JellyBelly I want to show the tasks title and the projects name it belongs to for all the tasks the user owns and is linked to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following query:

```
SELECT
  z.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.*
  FROM
    tasks as t1
    JOIN projects as p1 ON t1.project_id = p1.id
  WHERE
    t1.user_id = $userId
    AND p1.context_id = $contextId

  UNION

  SELECT
    t2.*
  FROM
    user_teams as utm
    JOIN teams as tm ON utm.team_id = tm.id
    JOIN project_teams as ptm ON tm.id = ptm.team_id
    JOIN projects as p2 ON ptm.project_id = p2.id
    JOIN tasks as t2 ON p2.id = t2.project_id
  WHERE
    utm.user_id = $userId
    AND p2.context_id = $contextId
) as z
ORDER BY 4 ASC
```

The query is simply the union of the two queries needed to retrieve the separate data you specified. This union is then ordered.

The query contains the variables $userId and $contextId.

The ORDER BY 4 ASC statement orders by the 4th column in the result set, in this case the title column from the tasks table.

Comment: If you have test data I could test the query, but it is too much work to setup some test data myself. Selecting the fields you want is simple, just add them to both select statements inside the union, but be aware both select statements should select the same fields. And you also need to update the order by clause.

Comment: I've tried your query but I'm getting 'every derived table must have it's own alias'. I've tripple checked and each reference to a table is followed by an alias :(

Comment: Sounds like the OP is using a different SQL product to you. That every derived table must have a correlation name is a Standard SQL-92 requirement (though pointless in this query) and the question only has the `sql` tag, I suggest you add one.

Comment: @onedaywhen I created this query without a particular SQL product in mind, it uses only fairly standard SQL operations afaik.

Comment: @iamjonesy I have updated some of the aliases in my post, maybe that fixes the problem? It is difficult for me to test though without test data. Posting your database create statements would be helpful.

Comment: I added an alias to the first from. So I did select z.* from (sele...) as z and it worked. The query itself seems to be producing the correct results too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tough part is on the join to tasks. Just do an OR condition in the ON clause

```
INNER JOIN tasks t
ON p.id = t.projectid
 or u.id = t.user_id
```

Full SQL clause

```
SELECT
   p.name,
   t.title
FROM
    users u 
    INNER JOIN users_teams ut
    on u.id = ut.user_id
    INNER JOIN projects_teams pt
    ON ut.team_id = pt.project_id
    INNER JOIN project p 
    ON project_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN tasks t
    ON p.id = t.projectid
     or u.id = t.user_id
```

Comment: This looks great Conrad, I'll try it out as soon as I can!